# ConcurrentHashMap guarantees

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, locking, concurrenthashmap

I have the concurrent hashmap in some service class:

```
class MyClass implements Flushable {
   private volatile ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Object> hashMap = ...

   public void add(int id, Object value) {
      hashMap.put(id, value);
   }

   @Override
   public void flush() throws IOException {
      hashMap.foreach((k, v) -> ...)
      hashMap.clear();
   }

}
```

Do I need to do some additional locking to be sure that:
 1. flush will process all map entries (what if add is invoked between foreach and clear?)
 2. clear will not remove entries which were inserted/updated after foreach

From javadoc, there is a guarantee that update happens before read. So as far as I understand `clear` will block `put` invocations, however to reach what I want I need some additional locks.

Comment: Yes, you need an external lock to be sure you don't clear something you haven't processed.

Comment: 1. and 2. are the same point. The `ConcurrentHashMap` can not make any guarantees about what will happen between the `forEach` call and the subsequent `clear`; you’re entirely outside its code, so how could any guarantee be imaginable?

Answer (score 0):

> In your case you need any extra locking here, both are operation should be locked  , clear method also do locking on segment level..

Comment: Yes, I understand that `clear` also has locks, however, question is about invocations of `add` between `foreach` and `clear`, while no locks are acquired.

Comment: No, its not thread safe, it will clear all values of map. Which are added, You can run your code in debug mode and check...

Comment: How does “locking on segment level” prevent concurrent `put` operations, e.g. in other segments? Not that such an implementation detail could be interpreted as “guaranty” anyway. Starting with Java 8, there are no segments anymore. But even [the older version’s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) clearly says “*there is not any support for locking the entire table in a way that prevents all access*”.